# if has theme mod

Tags: php, functions, get-theme-mod

Does someone know how to write the next line in wordpress PHP, because i'm not that great with PHP.

If_theme_mode has content echo { my content } else { other content };

thnx

Answer (score 4):

try this code:

```
if( get_theme_mod('your_setting_name') ){
  //your code
}else{
  //your code
}
```

**Note:** [get_theme_mod()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod) return false if no value exist for your setting

Answer (score 1):

You can check for a theme mod, echo it if it exists, or apply a default if not, all with one line:

```
echo get_theme_mod( 'example', 'Some default' );
```