# How to check if a Customizer setting is set?

Tags: php, functions, theme-customizer

I'm trying to setup a function that writes a meta tag into the header of my site.

Namely, I've set up a color chooser input like this:

```
function customizer_options($wp_customize) {

    $wp_customize -> add_setting ( 'chrome_theme', array( 'default' => '' ) );
    $wp_customize -> add_control ( new WP_Customize_Color_Control ( $wp_customize, 'chrome_theme', array(
        'label' => __('Chrome theme color', 'base-theme'),
        'description' => __('Tab color in Chrome for Android', 'base-theme'),
        'section' => 'title_tagline',
        'settings' => 'chrome_theme',
    )));

add_action( 'customize_register', 'customizer_options' );
```

then, I print the `meta` tag into my page `<head>` with this function:

```
function chrome_theme_meta() {

echo '<meta name="theme-color" content="', get_theme_mod( 'chrome_theme', '' ), '">';

}

add_action('wp_head', 'chrome_theme_meta');
```

---

It works as expected, except that it prints the `meta` tag also when no value is set, and I'd like to prevent this.

How can I check if the `chrome_theme` setting is set (so, not empty), and fire the `chrome_theme_meta` only if this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an action will fire the function regardless, but you can add an if statement to see if the value has been set. This way the  tag will not fire if the value is not set

```
function chrome_theme_meta() {
$chrome_theme = get_theme_mod( 'chrome_theme', '' );
  if(!empty($chrome_theme){//test to see if a value is set
    echo '<meta name="theme-color" content="', get_theme_mod( 'chrome_theme', '' ), '">';
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'chrome_theme_meta');
```

Alternately, the second (empty) parameter of `get_theme_mod( 'chrome_theme', '' )` is a fallback, so you could assign a default value if the setting has not been set.

Comment: Thank you; I'm aware of the fallback option, but I want to display this only if a value is manually inserted.

Comment: Ok, you can test the above code block, it will display only if a value is manually inserted.

Comment: I tried your solution, but I'm getting this error `Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)`

Comment: Right, silly me. Try the updated version.

Comment: It worked this time. Thank you, really kind form you.

Comment: I also found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/174941/98169), `get_theme_mod()` function returns `false` if no value exists [(link to Codex)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod), so it works even without explicitly stating the `!empty` part.

Comment: ^ Even more concise!